# Run php file from php script

Tags: php

```
  if (file_exists("displaytab.php")) {
    $sys = fopen("displaytab.php", "r+");
    system(".\displaytab.php"); }
```

I've tried to run the script in displaytab.php that I saved in the directory of my local server, I searched for the correct signature of `system()` and I used it, but it doesn't work. Am I using the wrong command or the right one but in the wrong way?

Comment: Don't do the `fopen` first. And how can you tell it isn't executing? What are you expecting when it works?

Comment: And does it work if from the command line you do `.\displaytab.php`? Are you sure the file is actually executable?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong command.  All you need to do is

```
include 'displaytab.php';
```

Comment: No!  `include` includes the specified file at the current point, as if the code was present in the current file.  So it gets parsed/executed like the code in the current file (and with the current scope)

Comment: Unless you are actively wanting to execute it as a command line script, not as part of the server application (so it won't produce output to the page, for example).  Which I don't recommend  - most hosting set-ups lock down that sort of execution on security grounds, apart from anything else.

Answer (score 0):

the php system function accepts a command to be executed you could try :

```
<?php
   $file = 'file.php';
   system('php '.$file);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To include php file inside another php file you should use `require()` or `include()`.

The different between this two functions is if you use `require()` and the file you invite contain fatal erros will block the script to execute but if you use `include()` the file execute however if contain erros.

And there is to other functions `require_once()` and `include_once` they do the same thing but if you want your file invite one time in php file.